# "Could not find the main class: com.cloudbees.sdk.boot.Launcher" after installing Cloudbees SDK

Tags: cloudbees

I have installed the Cloudbees SDK on my Ubuntu 12.04 system following [this doc](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK). When I run `bees help` I get the following message :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/cloudbees/sdk/boot/Launcher Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cloudbees.sdk.boot.Launcher     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266) Could not find
>   the main class: com.cloudbees.sdk.boot.Launcher. Program will exit.

It's maybe useful to note that I alredy installed an older version of the Cloudbees SDK and I started by uninstalling it by removing the installation folder and the .bees folder in my home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your bees command may be trying to launch with jars from an incorrect location.  Make sure that your BEES_HOME environment variable is pointing at the same directory where there bees command/script you are running comes from.

Comment: I was using the ~ notation to set the $BEES_HOME env variable. I change it to a full path and it works, thanks!